# Azure Application Gateway with ACI instance in the backendpool giving '502 Bad Gateway' error when invoked from postman

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I created an application gateway in Azure. I have set an ACI instance as backend target. The ACI is a linux container instance. It contains my WebApis. When I try to invoke the WebAPI from Postman using the public IP address of the application gateway, I get '502 bad gateway error'. I could not find much resource online that was using an ACI as backend target in an Application Gateway.
I referred to this site - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/application-gateway-web-application-firewall-portal to configure application gateway. Here they have VM as backend target. Instead I used private IP address of my container instance as backend target.
In 'Backend Pool' of my application gateway, I selected 'IP address or FQDN' as target type and provided the private IP address of my container instance.

Would appreciate any input/help on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your problem?
Locally the docker cpntainer works as expected (correct ports configured)
Http traffic or https ?
The ip address of the aci is the one you have in the backend pool?
Need more info to be able to help.